# Which Scriptures say that by chanting Lord's name during the time of one's death one can attain "Moksha"?

Tags: scripture, shiva, puranas, bhagavad-gita, moksha

In [Bhagawat Gita](http://www.sanatan.org/en/a/270.html) Sri Krishna says that one who remembers the Supreme Lord and Pranava(OM) while dying reaches the higher states of bliss or the Supreme Lord Himself.

> ओमित्येकाक्षरं ब्रह्म व्याहरन्मामनुस्मरन् । यः प्रयाति त्यजन्देहं स
>   याति परमां गतिम् ।। – Shrimadbhagwadgita, Adhyaya 8, Shloka 13
>
> Meaning-Meaning : (Shrikrushna says) The one who dies while chanting
>   ‘Om’ and remembering me is elevated to a very high level after death.
>
> अन्तकाले च मामेव स्मरन्मुक्त्वा कलेवरम् । यः प्रयाति स मद्भावं याति
>   नास्त्यत्र संशयः ।। – Shrimadbhagwadgita, Adhyaya 8, Shloka 5
>
> Meaning : (Shrikrushna says) There is no doubt that the one who
>   remembers me while dying reaches me.

**Question-Are there any other Scriptures that say by chanting Lord's name while dying one can attain moksha(liberation)?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/brahma%20vaivartha/bookview.php?chapnum=2) Brahma Vaivarta Purana chapter states that, one, who chants the name **"Shiva"**, during his/her dying moments, **is sure to attain moksha.**

> Shri Krishna then revealed the excellent value of Shiva Linga
>   Sthapana or establishing a Shiva Linga; he said: *Maha Deva Maha Deva
>   Maha Deveti vaadinah, Paschaadyaami Mahaastrasto naama shravana
>   lobhatah, **Shiveti mantramucchharya praanamstyajati yo narah/ Koti
>   janmaarjitaat Paapaanmukto muktim prayaati sah, Shivam kalyaana
>   vachanam kalyaanam kalyaanam Muktivaachikam**/ Yaatsattha Prabhavettena
>   sa Shivah parikeertitah/* (If some body recites Maha Deva, Maha Deva
>   and Maha Deva, I am tempted to be behind him and follow him; **if
>   somebody takes Shiva's name at the time of his death, that person
>   would be freed from the sins committed by his/her previous crores of
>   lives and most certainly secure Moksha. The word Shiva stands for
>   Kalyana or Propitiousness and the word Kalyana denotes Mukti. Also
>   the letter Shi stood for Paapa naashan and Va for Moksha**

Answer (score 7):

The story of [Ajamila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajamila) in [Bhagawata Purana](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6) is an example of the power of chanting the Lord's Name in the last moments of life, even if accidentally.  Although the reference is not directly to Moksha, the Vishnudutas avert the immediate mortality of Ajamila, because he chanted the Lord's Name in the last moment.

Of course, the inner significance is that, to be able to chant the Lord's Name at the time of death, one needs to train the mind throughout the life. [Sri Ramakrishna mentions a story](http://www.belurmath.org/gospel/) to illustrate this point about training the mind to chant the Lord's name. A businessman named all his four sons after the names of Lord Narayana, in the hope that, like Ajamila, he will call out one of those names in his last moments, and thereby attain liberation. In the last moment, he called out the names of all the four sons. While they reached his bedside, he exclaimed, *'You fellows! If all of you come here to my bedside, who will take care of the business ?*' . And he breathed his last!. He finally thought of his money, instead of chanting the Lord's Name.

Comment: Nice answer but not as  precise as i would have liked .....You are right about chanting holy names all throughout the life each day ,each moment..this part is already discussed in the link given in my question..you mite have a read...Its highly improbable that a person will chant god's name during death(even if he knows about its supreme benefits) simply becoz  **1**he wont be able to predict the precise time of his death and **2** mostly he won't be concious or mentally alert  to chant...

Comment: ---so the ones who chant at death are very few and very rare beings who r carrying forward lots of punya from the present & previous lives..

Comment: Yes, to bementally alert is important. Yes, punya plays a role. But it doesn't have to be punya. In Bhagavad Gita, Krishna mentions that wayward nature of mind can be re-directed by Abhyasa and Vairagya (constant practice and dispassion). Mahatma Gandhi chanted Rama's after he was shot by the assassin. It's true the nature of final moments, whether conscious or not conscious, is not in our hands to predict. But, assuming, we would be conscious, to chant the Lord's Name setting aside other thoughts, needs lifelong practice, that's on us to try. Such inclination may itself be a result of punya.

Answer (score 3):

(Not specific to chanting name of Krishna), I'm here quoting verse which has similar meaning/preaching to that of Bhagavad-Gita (which is believed to be an essene of Upanishads) you've mentioned.

Chhandogya Upanishad : Adhyaya 3, Khanda 14 (also known as Shandilya Vidya (which Starts from popular Upanidhadic declaration : *Sarva Khalvidam Brahman*), Verse 14:

> सर्वकर्मा सर्वकामः सर्वगन्धः सर्वरसः सर्वमिदमभ्यात्तोऽवाक्यनादर एष म आत्मान्तर्हृदय एतद्ब्रह्मैतमितः प्रेत्याभिसंभवितास्मीति यस्य स्यादद्धा न विचिकित्सास्तीति ह स्माह शाण्डिल्यः शाण्डिल्यः ॥ ३.१४.४॥
>
> 4. He whose creation is this universe, who cherishes all desires,  who contains all odours, who is endowed with all tastes, who  embraces all this, who never speaks and who is without  longing-He is my Self within the heart, He is that Brahman.  **When I shall have departed hence I shall certainly reach Him:  one who has this faith and has no doubt will certainly attain to  that Godhead.** Thus said Sandilya, yea, thus he said.

Comment: Ok upvoted for ur effort..but actually the answer is not quite relevant to my question..